# 401, no token provided - Spotify API fetch - despite existing in header

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, spotify

When I run this code I can see that there is a header with the token included in it but I still get "401, no token provided" on the second request. The request for a token goes through fine and outputs to the console fine (I've replaced secrets with *s). I've tried a variety of different ways of setting the header and all did the same thing. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
async function getAuth() {
      const res = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=***&client_secret=***'
      });
      return res.json();
    }
    
    async function fetchWebApi(endpoint, method, token) {
        console.log('Bearer ' + token)
      const res = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/' + endpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
        
      });
      return res.json();
    }

    async function getTopTracks(token){
      // Endpoint reference : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks
      return ( await fetchWebApi(
        'v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=short_term&limit=5', 'GET', token
      )).items;
    }
    
    //6p21dRudS9FmcyGvKWPq2R?si=591aadc63f934b7c
    async function getRandomPlaylist(token) {
        return ( await fetchWebApi (
            'v1/me/playlists/3cEYpjA9oz9GiPac4AsH4n/tracks', 'GET', token
        )).items;
    }

    // getTopTracks().then(data => console.log(data))
    
    
    
    getAuth().then(data => {
        myToken = data['access_token']
        console.log(myToken)
        getRandomPlaylist(myToken).then(aplaylist => console.log(aplaylist))    
    }
```

How it looks on network tab of developers tool

[image: Network tab]

Comment: Can you show us how your requests look alike in your Dev Tools -> Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

From your network tab, error code is 403.
The error 403 means that you do not have the necessary permissions to access the requested resource. This could be because you are not logged in, or because you do not have the correct permissions.

You might:

1. have an expired token. Try with a new token after making `refreshToken` call.
2. want to open your api portal and check if you have permission to access top tracks.

I found this issue which looks similar to the problem you have.

https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1118

Let me know if helped.

Comment: The code is refreshing the token every time though isn't it?